# Parameter pass method two method in java

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

**please let me know. a method of having two in one class and the way of passing parameters system?**

here you get 3 method in one class.

Example :

> in the first method there is a method called an assigned sinhala word
>   viriable. in the secound one there is a another veriable called
>   english word. but all these two should run  in the third method. it
>   should print as follows **`(sinhala english)`**.

dear friends kindly tell me how to 
perform this?

```
//This is my third.

public void search() {
        DefaultTableModel tbl = (   DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        tbl.setRowCount(0);
        try {
            con = boxdemo.bd_test();
            String query = "select language from language where language like '/*first_veriable*/' or language like '/*second_veriable*/'  ;";
            Statement stm = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(query); 

            while (rs.next()) {
                Vector v = new Vector(); 
                v.add(rs.getString("language"));
                tbl.addRow(v);   
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

//This is my first.

 private void jCheckBox1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        

        String Sinhala = "sinhala";
        if (jCheckBox1.isSelected()) {
            search();
        } 
    }                                       

//This is my second.

    private void jCheckBox2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
        String Arbic = "English";
        if (jCheckBox2.isSelected()) {
            search();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Post http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to get answer.

Comment: can you post your code which you tried?

Comment: Hello @RedAnz, please edit your question and append code. Then it's easier to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to construct your query depending on the selected `JCheckBox`es.

The below code snippet works, if:

1. You created a `JCheckBox[] checkBoxes` field that contains all the checkboxes with languages.
2. The text of all those `JCheckBox` is exactly the `String` that should be placed inside the `'`.

```
public void search() {
    // join text of all selected JCheckBoxes from checkBoxes array
    String conditions = Arrays.stream(checkBoxes) // create a stream of language checkboxes
            .filter(JCheckBox::isSelected) // restrict stream to selected checkboxes
            .map(JCheckBox::getText) // convert from checkbox to query string
            .collect(Collectors.joining("' or language like '")); // join query strings using a delimiter

    ...

    if (!conditions.isEmpty()) {
        // at least one language selected
        ...

        String query = "select language from language where language like '"+ conditions+"'  ;";

        ...    
    }

    ...
}
```

If you want to use different `String`s in the query and as text of the checkboxes you could e.g. store those `String`s in a field `HashMap<JCheckBox, String> checkboxToQueryString` and use `map(checkboxToQueryString::get)` instead of `map(JCheckBox::getText)`.

If you use a java version <8 it shouldn't be too difficult to rewrite the code part involving `Stream`s and method references.

Note that using streams for only 2 checkboxes is a bit of an overkill. You can simplyfy the code as you feel appropriate. The approach shown above works for a arbitrary number of checkboxes however.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
class Test123 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printSinhala();
        printEnglish();

    }

    public static void printSinhala() {
        System.out.print("(sinhala");

    }

    public static void printEnglish() {
        System.out.print(" english)");

    }
}
```

P.S: Please do some research and show some efforts, you are not supposed to ask questions without any effort, and Ideally I am not supposed to encourage such questions by answering..